# Пробел в переменной Js

Tags: javascript

Нужно опционально вставлять пробел между суммой и знаком валюты. Выдает ошибку **indent is not defined**.

```
function setCurrencySign(price)
{
    if (params.indent == 0){
        let indent = '';
    } else {
        let indent = ' ';
    }

    if (dataCurrency.symbol != ''){
        if (params.curlocation == 'right'){
            price = price + indent + dataCurrency.symbol;
        } else {
            price = dataCurrency.symbol + indent + price;
        }
    } else {
        price = dataCurrency.code + indent + price;
    }

    return price;
}
```

1. Как правильно задать пробел в переменную indent?
2. Оптимизировать всю функцию в целом.

Comment: замени `let` на `var`

Comment: Да, дошло) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let indent = params.indent == 0? '' : ' ';
```

Вы объявляете переменные `indent` внутри блоков `{...}` - в Вашем коде это две разные переменные. Снаружи этих блоков их не видно.

Comment: Как ни странно, но это сработало. Хотя суть та же. Видимо так **indent** принимает вид стоки.

Comment: @MaXX Кому-то странно, а для кого-то - в порядке вещей.

Comment: Ну с этим уж точно не поспоришь) Спасибо!!!

Comment: Скобки лишние...